# Menu gets wrap in Div - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Working on Wordpress menu: with Bootstrap

My ul li gets wrap within Ul and creates Div. 
Screenshot attached: 
[image]

It seems it automatically adds classes to menu li and and prevents the bootstrap styles and classes

My wp menu function :

```
/**
 * Get our wp_nav_menu() fallback, wp_page_menu(), to show a home link.
 */
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing in the theme template the nav menu function like this :

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => '', // <- This empty = no container
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

Source : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Take a look at the `container` index of the defaults array.